# Eloquent ORM - get first 100 letters of a column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to get the first 100 letters of a column?
I could use `substr($text, 0, 100)`, but for performance reasons I want to select directly from the database the first 100 letters. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL you could do something like `->selectRaw('SUBSTR(column_name, 0, 100)')`

Other languages use something like `SUBSTRING()` as a function. You can look them up for your database driver.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw expression:   `Model::select(DB::raw('substr(column_name, 0, 100)'));`